# What is "anti-optimization" about?

Tags: terminology, optimization

I was wondering what "anti-optimization" is about? Is it related to optimization? What topics does it cover?

All I can find out from Google is [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6TJ4-42WP6GH-M&_user=10&_coverDate=07/31/2001&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=abd081ecba664ee663f2157095a2bb4a&searchtype=a). It looks like having some relation with probability and optimization?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Anti-optimization* is a term popularized by Isaac Elishakoff for an approach to safety factors in engineering structures which he describes as pessimistic and searching for least favourable responses, in combination with optimistization techniques but in contrast to probabilistic approaches.

You might be able to discover more from the preface or first chapter of *[Optimization and Anti-Optimization of Structures under Uncertainty](http://www.worldscibooks.com/engineering/p678.html)*

Answer (score 2):

Anti-optimization is a buzzword for "worst case" and the "hybrid optimization/anti-optimization" is a buzzword for [Maximin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximin_%28decision_theory%29%22maximin%22).

It should be pointed out that the invention of such buzzwords does not represent  any scientific progress. In fact, it is counter-productive distraction. This is so especially in cases where the use of such buzzwords gives the (false) illusion that the theory/method described is new, while in fact the only thing new is the use of new buzzwords.